# How to count in embedded document of MongoDB for each _id

Tags: mongodb

I've document which looks like:

```
_id: 1,
    chat: [
    {
     sender: "michael",
     message: "hello",
     status: "pending",
     receiver: "jennifer"
    },
    {
     sender: "michael",
     message: "how are you ?",
     status: "sent",
     receiver: "jennifer"
    }
    ]
_id: 2,
    chat: [
    {
     sender: "michael",
     message: "hello",
     status: "pending",
     receiver: "bobby"
    },
    {
     sender: "michael",
     message: "how are you ?",
     status: "pending",
     receiver: "bobby"
    }
    ]
```

How can I get count of status = "pending" from embedded document ?
I want the result looks like:

```
_id: 1,
sender: "michael",
receiver: "jennifer",
status_pending: 1
_id: 2,
sender: "michael",
receiver: "bobby",
status_pending: 2,
```

I don't know how to use $unwind, $group, $size in MongoDB. Please someone help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `$unwind` chat, then `$group` by id, sender and receiver and count using `$sum` and then `$project` to return final result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$chat'},
    {$match: {'chat.status': 'pending'}},
    {$group: {
        _id: {_id: '$_id', sender: '$chat.sender',receiver: '$chat.receiver'},
        status_pending: {$sum: 1}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: '$_id._id', 
        sender: '$_id.sender', 
        receiver: '$_id.receiver', 
        status_pending: 1
    }}
])
```

Final result

```
[{"status_pending":2,"_id":2,"sender":"michael","receiver":"bobby"},{"status_pending":1,"_id":1,"sender":"michael","receiver":"jennifer"}]
```

Comment: It couldn't work sir.. When the status was "sent", status_pending still count. Can you look at my question please ? :) It was edited

Comment: $project stands for ? Actually that code was error, but when I didn't use $project it works.

Comment: If you remove $project stage you get result like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1741/, also i tested it and it works fine, make sure its same as my code.

Comment: Yeahh you're right. But, the code is working for me looks like this <pre>db.chat.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$chat"},{"$match":{'chat.status':"pending"}},{"$group":{"_id":{"_id": '$_id', "sender": '$chat.sender', "receiver": '$chat.reveicer'},"status_pending":{"$sum":1}}},{"$project":{"_id":"$_id._id","sender":"$_id.sender","receiver":"$_id.receiver","status_pending":1}}]).forEach(printjson)<code>